# Publishing and subscribing to node-redis for an image resizing job after form POST

Tags: node.js, redis, publish-subscribe, node-redis

I've got a form submission that accepts an image. I'm creating thumbnails (resizing and pushing to S3) with the image upon submission, and it's taking awhile and blocking so I've decided I want to push it to a message queue and have that handle it.

I've decided to go with node-redis, since I'm already using redis in my stack. What I'm unclear on is how exactly the implementation would look (in its most basic form).

Consider some pseudocode below as:

```
var redis = require('redis'),
    client = redis.createClient();

function listenForJob() {
  client.on('message', function(msg) {
  // msg is our temporary path name
    // Kick of resize and push to s3 job
  });
}

// Attached to my route where I POST to (e.g. /submit)
exports.form = function(req, res, next) {
  // Input comes in, and image comes in as req.files
  // and a temporary image is saved in /uploads
  // which I'll save as the image submission for now
  // until the process to resize and push to s3 happens.

  listenForJob();

  // Save to db
  var data = {
    title: req.body.title,
    img: req.files.path // save temp file
  }
  connection.query('INSERT INTO submissions SET ?', data, function(err, rows) {

  // Publish to our redis client?
  client.publish('message', req.files.path);
  connection.release();
  res.redirect('/submissions');
  });
};
```

Is this implementation even remotely the correct way to approach this? I'm new to taskworkers/message queues so I'm just wondering how to do implement it properly (given my use case).

Comment: Take a look at http://redis.io/commands/blpop you can use a redis list as a queue.

Comment: You're looking into doing the message queue our the Redis part?

Comment: As for the queue, you also might want to have the job check of we're at `maxParallelJobs` in that on.message listener. If it is, skip the job. And also, when the job is done poll the message queue for such rejected jobs. Finally, on.error of your job (especially async errors) make sure to restart the job and return it to the queue.

Comment: Or use some ready-made job broker.

Comment: @Zlatko Cool is there some kind of documentation for handling the on error restarting? I've put up a gist here https://gist.github.com/anonymous/d76aab2b86069464326d which shows how I'll be using this thing. Using node-redis fwiw.

Comment: Oh, your gist handles the redis client handling. That's a totally separate thing then what you're doing above. What I've meant is that you have to make sure that the 'taskworkers' you mention are ok - if they break, your job needs to be put back on the queue. Say you're doing some, I don't know, image resizing. Say your resizing fails because the S3 ran out of space. You've pulled the job, but you didn't complete it. If you just ignore _that_ error, your job will be off the queue and never completed.